# How to NOT change camera center upon GeolocateControl trigger?

Tags: mapbox-gl-js

I have a Mapbox web app map that I want to add the user's location to, but NOT have the map automatically recenter itself on the user's location. The example code here https://docs.mapbox.com/mapbox-gl-js/example/locate-user/ works great, I just don't want the map to recenter on the user.

This is specifically the code I'm using:

```
// GEO LOCATE USER! 
const  geolocate  = new   mapboxgl.GeolocateControl({
    positionOptions: {
        enableHighAccuracy: false
    },
    trackUserLocation: false
});
map.addControl(geolocate,"bottom-left");
geolocate.trigger();
```

Is there a way to have the geolocate.trigger() be a passive experience and not recenter the map, just add the user's location to it?

Comment: Did you try passing in a `fitBoundsOptions` parameter? https://docs.mapbox.com/mapbox-gl-js/api/#geolocatecontrol

Answer (score 3):

Mapbox-GL doesn't expose an official API to disable auto-tracking of a user's location with the camera, but you can monkey-patch it to accomplish what you want:

```
const locate = new mapboxgl.GeolocateControl({
    positionOptions: { enableHighAccuracy: true },
    trackUserLocation: true
})
// hacky workaround for the fact that mapbox doesn't let you disable camera auto-tracking
locate._updateCamera = () => {}
this.map.addControl(locate)
```

This works by replacing the internal `_updateCamera` method with a noop:
- https://github.com/mapbox/mapbox-gl-js/blob/2693518e8d042b3120c33f08433abbc3b114d25c/src/ui/control/geolocate_control.js#L187